# How to close popup window in ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

I want to close a popup window when i click a linkbutton in asp page.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb" runat="server" Text="<%#Text %>" OnClick="javascript:window.close()" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

The error code is : "CS1026: ) expected"

I've searched for it on internet, but i can't find the solution. Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb" runat="server" Text="<%#Text %>" OnClientClick="window.close();"></asp:LinkButton>
```

or

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb" runat="server" Text="<%#Text %>" OnClientClick="javascript: window.close();"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb" runat="server" Text="<%#Text %>" OnClientClick="this.close();"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: It will generate a conflit with other code, i can't close it.

Comment: Just replace "this.close" with "window.close" will make it work. Thank you Ghyath!!!